# Creating/drawing map (especially indoor)?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, indoor

I'm currently developing an indoor map/room plan for an university project. I've already searched through Stack Exchange to figure it out but I couldn't find anything similar.

So what I currently do to create a indoor map/room plan is to use QGIS and draw points, lines and rectangles. It has a nice snapping feature and other stuff that makes the map creation slightly convenient. But I have problems when it comes to alignment, squareness etc. That's why I'm searching for a more convenient solution to draw maps, especially indoor maps.

What I'm **not** looking for is an app or business solution thats tracks my movement and creates a map with it. I really would like to draw the map on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong Forum.

Use autocad.

There is a free student version available if you are a student....i am not saying that you dont need to be a student to get it you can be "home school" and still get your 3 year version.

So basically get the autocad 3 year student version.

Answer (score 1):

As well as AutoCAD there's also Google SketchUp which i've toyed with a little. Less fully featured but might be a nice easy intuitive way to get what you want done, for free.